# Eval text not changing using asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

Why is the text in the top not changing??

```
<%# Eval("StatusID") == "I" ? "a" : "d" %> //stubbern as an Ox
<%# Eval("StatusID") %>                    //changes just fine
```

(not meeting the standards, adding fluff)

I have tried many different variations as well as code behind attempts without success. I've even switched my code base to VB.net as an attempt as I have seen a popular answer here in vb.net, no success.

**EDIT:** Found a solution, however I didn't find the issue. Maybe someone more knowledgeable than I can answer me why the above won't work

```
<%# Eval("StatusID").ToString().ToLower().Contains("i")  ? "a" : "d" %>`
```

Comment: What does the top line do?

Comment: @krillgar It's https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: What is the value of the StatusID you are getting from code behind?

Comment: What is the data-binding context? Can you use alternative approaches to render data?

Comment: StatusID has additional white spaces or actual value is lower case?

Comment: If it works with a `.Contains`, seems like your StatusID value isn't a single character. Try to display the `.ToString().Length` property

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh its either I or A

Comment: @Hakunamatata no white spaces , sorry possible the datatype isn't string?

Comment: @RubensFarias will give that a shot and update

Comment: @Pakk Yes, I know what a ternary operator is. I meant, what is it giving you vs what you expect it to give you?

Comment: @krillgar it was giving me only the false condition. So somehow the control is a string before calling .ToString() ?? not sure what else it type it would be.